# Get from observable no more than every 100ms, but always get the final value

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a worker which exposes a `Subject<string>`, which publishes log messages very quickly. Writing to the console is slow, so I want to only write to the console every 100ms, at the most. When the task is finished I want to write out the most recent published string, to avoid having things like `Doing work 2312/2400 ...done`. (or even `...done` if the task takes <100ms.)

I'm new to reactive extensions, and though I've heard talks about how awesome they are, this is the first time I've noticed a situation where they could help me.

So, in summary,
1) Don't give me an event more than once every 100ms
2) I need to know about the final event, regardless of when it arrives.

I'll put my code in an answer below, but please suggest something better. Maybe I've missed a standard call which achieves this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you make out *if* the observable that is the source of your events called `OnCompleted()` when it's done. This will do the trick by itself:

```
observable.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Subscribe(log);
```

This is because `Sample` will fire one last time when the source of it's events completes. Here's a full test:

```
var sub = new Subject<string>();
var gen = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)).Select((_,i) => i).Subscribe(i => sub.OnNext(i.ToString()));

sub.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
   .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

Thread.Sleep(3500);
sub.OnCompleted();
```

Even though I sleep for 3.5 seconds, 4 events fire, the last one firing when I call `OnCompleted()`.

Another point to note is that it's bad form if `Worker.GetObservable()` actually returns a `Subject<string>` - even if it is that in the Worker class, what it **really** should do is return just the `IObservable<string>` interface. This is more than mere style, it is a separation of concerns and returning the minimum functional interface needed.

Comment: Notice you can use AsObservable to hide the identity of the underlying object, in this case a Subject. If you simply return the object as an IObservable, the user can still cast back to an IObserver and pump data in.

AsObservable is precisely what you're looking for to help with your "separation of concerns" here.

Comment: @BartDeSmet excellent, had no idea just returning `IObservable` wasn't enough. That's gold.

Comment: If I try to do a Console.WriteLine("Done.") after the OnCompleted call, then "Done." appears before the write resulting from the OnCompleted call... but this might be a separate question...

Comment: ...ah found the Subscribe overload which takes Action OnCompleted. I'll write out the done in that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I've come up with, which seems to do the job. I'm not sure how correct or idiomatic it is though.

```
var observable = Worker.GetObservable(); //Actually a Subject<string>
Action<string> log = x => Console.Write("\r" + x);
string latest = "";
using(observable.Subscribe(x => latest = x))
using(observable.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Subscribe(log))
{
    Worker.DoWorkWithLogs();
    log(latest);
}
Console.WriteLine(" ...done.");
```

Comment: Will your subject have 'OnCompleted' called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BufferWithTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707353%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) function.